# Is the word base a "magic" word in RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs

Is the word `base` a "magic" word in RequireJS?

What does it refer to by default?

Comment: When used as a module name, config key, or...? The [source code](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js) doesn't show any suspicious uses to the word "base" when ctrl+f-ing. It would be useful to know *why* you are asking such a specific question.

Comment: What makes you think that it is?  In what context do you think that "base" is a magic word?

Comment: Are you trying to use RequireJS and Karma together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed, Karma is likely your culprit, which puts all resources on /base before running.

First, confirm you have the npm package "karma-requirejs" installed.

Check your Karma config file and ensure you have the "frameworks" array include "requirejs". Here's what mine looks like:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
```

Also, in your files array, have the last file be your require config and all other files above specifying not to be included on page load (included: false). Again, here's a sample from one of my projects Karma config files:

```
files: [
     //other files here, such as:
     { pattern: 'app.js', included: false },
     // require config needs to be last; see http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/requirejs.html
     'config/require.config.js'
],
```

Please note that my require config bootstraps the application as well by calling require(["app"]), which starts the require/fetch process.

Assuming:

- "baseUrl" is pointing to your webroot (it can be relative),
- "frameworks" includes "requirejs",
- "files" array includes all your dependencies but doesn't included them up front (that's require's job) and the config is last to follow,

...you should have good karma. :)

Good luck!